# Not able to push packages on Octopus

Tags: octopus-deploy

Build pipeline fails at task 'push packages to Octopus'

## ##[section]Starting: Push Packages to Octopus

Task         : Push Package(s) to Octopus
Description  : Push your NuGet or Zip package to your Octopus Deploy Server
Version      : 4.0.387
Author       : Octopus Deploy

## Help         : Version: 4.0.387. [More Information](https://g.octopushq.com/TFS-VSTS)

65978706-f70e-4ac0-8dc7-7f61db0ce4d8 exists true
Attempting to contact https://g.octopushq.com to find Octo command line tool version latest
Checking local tool cache
Found tool in cache: Octo 6.13.1 x64
Looking for E:\vsts\a_tool\Octo\6.13.1\x64*Octo.dll
Prepending PATH environment variable with directory: E:\vsts\a_tool\Octo\6.13.1\x64
[command]C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /D /S /C "E:\vsts\a_tool\Octo\6.13.1\x64\Octo.cmd version"

E:\vsts\a\5833\s>dotnet "E:\vsts\a_tool\Octo\6.13.1\x64/Octo.dll" version 
6.13.1
[command]C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /D /S /C "E:\vsts\a_tool\Octo\6.13.1\x64\Octo.cmd push "--server=https://octopus.bentley.com/" "--apiKey=***" "--space=Spaces-1" "--package=E:/vsts/a/5833/a/PGDQApp.2019.9.16.2.nupkg" "--overwrite-mode=OverwriteExisting""

E:\vsts\a\5833\s>dotnet "E:\vsts\a_tool\Octo\6.13.1\x64/Octo.dll" push "--server=https://octopus.bentley.com/" "--apiKey=***" "--space=Spaces-1" "--package=E:/vsts/a/5833/a/PGDQApp.2019.9.16.2.nupkg" "--overwrite-mode=OverwriteExisting" 
Octopus Deploy Command Line Tool, version 6.13.1

Detected automation environment: "AzureDevOps"
Found space: Default (Spaces-1)
Space name specified, process is now running in the context of space: Default
Handshaking with Octopus Server: https://octopus.bentley.com/
Handshake successful. Octopus version: 2019.7.13; API version: 3.0.0
Authenticated as: Neha Lahoti  
Pushing package: E:\vsts\a\5833\a\PGDQApp.2019.9.16.2.nupkg...
Requesting signature for delta compression from the server for upload of a package with id 'PGDQApp' and version '2019.9.16.2'
No package with the same ID exists on the server
Falling back to pushing the complete package to the server
You do not have permission to perform this action. Please contact your Octopus administrator. Missing permission: BuiltInFeedPush
Exit code: -5

### [error]Error: The process 'E:\vsts\a_tool\Octo\6.13.1\x64\Octo.cmd' failed with exit code 4294967291

### [error]Failed to push package. The process 'E:\vsts\a_tool\Octo\6.13.1\x64\Octo.cmd' failed with exit code 4294967291

### [section]Finishing: Push Packages to Octopus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You do not have permission to perform this action. Please contact your Octopus administrator. Missing permission: BuiltInFeedPush Exit code: -5

Seems like you are missing permissions to push a package?

Keep in mind that in Octopus you need to have permissions to *all the projects* that are using that package in order to push a new version of it (as pushing a package might trigger a new deployment on specific projects)